# How to display many photo albums related to category

Tags: categories

I am developing one project and in this project i have to display many photos albums related to each category name. 
**Particular.**

```
Photos [Custom page.Redirect to next sub-category with name {personal} ] 
        sub-category Personal Photos
        sub-category Professional Photos
        ........
```

I want all of content that i describe in the wireframe below. I want this for each category, and every album to be next to each other like Rome, Madrit album, etc also below this there is a field with number that describes the number of photos for each album like **Rome / 28 photos.**
[image: Wireframe]

I read many articles with multiple solutions. Some of them recommend to create this with Custom Post Types, i think that in addition i want to create a Custom Category Template. What are your opinion, how can organize all of these content and if you have any other suggestions, i would like to read.

Thanks i advance.

Comment: There are really just so many ways to do this it makes it hard to asnwer, can you provide more details on why you don't just use the default category/posts of WordPress?

Comment: @Wyck. Thanks for the answer. This part of my project (uploading photos) i want to be as simple as possible, and of course be done as I thought. My project will be managed from the client and I do not want to interfere with it at all. Ι will use the WP as CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it simple and unique I would use a custom post type combined with a custom taxonomy called "Photos".

Registering a custom post type allows you to customize what the input is and the dashboard, along with making it easier to work with code wise, since it is separate from the default "posts".

You can find a reference here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
And an example here (the codex example is horribly messy):  https://gist.github.com/2377383

For the category I think it would be worth registering a custom taxonomy, it makes dealing with unique output easier then using the default categories. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Tie the "Photos" taxonomy into your custom post type, then create some custom templates based off of this and you are all set.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Wynk, useful advice. this was one of my thought. Some clarifications yet, but for categories. According to Template_Hierarchy i will create a custom template category for each category? Right? category-ID.php etc.. I Know how to create a Custom page template, but how can create for categories? Sorry if I'm off topic. I will return later with more with more questions and solutions. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: My thoughts:I will create 4 Custom Post Types for each category that i want then for each category i will create one custom page template. But my problem is how i can connect these custom post types with the categories that i have to my main menu bar.

Comment: The templates are "hierarchical" as seen here, http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Comment: i have read this. But i would know that if i thought correctly

Comment: Is any solution of my question? I am a little confused. My thought is to create  two custom fields for posts (the title of album and the number of photos) then create a simple custom template and publish these with image gallery plugin. I thought right? I want feedback.